# What should be @JsonFormat(pattern="") in Spring-boot for given example

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

Using Spring-boot RESTful service,in that receiving JSON file which contain DateTime in following format **"2017-08-16T16:08:25.000Z"** and JsonFormat tries are e.g

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") 
@JsonFormat(JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern="yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

but none of format match accepting.
jar used as shown below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
```

so what should be JSON format pattern to accept such json data -Date with Time

Comment: Did you check with : `@JsonFormat(JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ")`

Comment: @sunkuet02 as I mentioned ,tried that also

Comment: Apologize,  you have tried `yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` My  pattern has a silly change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the javadocs carefully.
Quoting from the [javadoc of `@JsonFormat`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html)

> - `Date`: Shape can be `JsonFormat.Shape.STRING` or `JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER`;
>   pattern may contain [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)-compatible pattern definition.

and quoting from the [javadoc of `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> Within date and time pattern strings, unquoted letters from
> `'A'` to `'Z'` and from `'a'` to `'z'` are interpreted as
> pattern letters [...].
> Text can be quoted using single quotes (`'`) to avoid interpretation.

Hence you need to use `'T'` instead of `T` in the pattern for `@JsonFormat`:

```
pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```